# Python script generates all image files when run manually but not when run as a cronjob

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a Python3 script that generates png plots using `matplotlib`.  When I run it manually on my server, all of the plots are updated but when I run it as a cronjob, only 3 of 9 are properly updated.  I am using absolute paths for everything and the file permissions/ownerships are all identical.

What is puzzling is that the cronjob updates only some of the figures but not others whereas running manually, they're all updated.  Moreover, the three figures that are updated are created at the end of the script.

**Edit: Added some sample code**

This does not update my figure when run as a cronjob:

```
grouped = daily_data.groupby('Province_State')

grouped.apply(lambda d: plt.plot(d.date, d.Incident_Rate, label=d.Province_State.iloc[0]))
plt.savefig('incidence_rate.png')
plt.close()
```

But this does:

```
plt.plot(daily_data.loc[daily_data.Province_State=='Utah', 'date'],
         daily_data.loc[daily_data.Province_State=='Utah', 'incidence_change'],
         'C1', label="Daily")
plt.plot(daily_data.loc[daily_data.Province_State=='Utah', 'date'],
         daily_data.loc[daily_data.Province_State=='Utah', 'rolling_incidence_change_5_day'],
         'C1--', label='5 day MA')
plt.plot(daily_data.loc[daily_data.Province_State=='Utah', 'date'],
         daily_data.loc[daily_data.Province_State=='Utah', 'rolling_incidence_change_10_day'],
         'C1-.', label='10 day MA')
plt.plot(daily_data.loc[daily_data.Province_State=='Utah', 'date'],
         daily_data.loc[daily_data.Province_State=='Utah', 'rolling_incidence_change_15_day'],
         color='C1', linestyle='dotted', label='15 day MA')
plt.savefig(base_directory+'rolling_incidence_change.png')
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Having posted the code, I now see exactly what the problem is.  I haven't provided a path for the figures that fail...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can debug it by sending the output and the stderr to a file and comparing the manually run output file and  the cron output file

```
yourscript > /tmp/out.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: When run manually, it creates no output and when I added `> /tmp/out.txt 2>&1` it created a size 0 file.

Comment: Yes, and now you can strategically add some debug statements that show what is going on. Your goal is discovering the difference between  manually and cron run. So find out where they start to behave differently.

Comment: I've added print statements at various stages and the output from running it manually and as a cronjob are identical.  Not sure if there is any way to force `matplotlib` to give me more information.

Comment: @ruud you shouldn't [change the meaning of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62147854/5) if you edit a question. I approved it for now and edited the problem back in. If you edit out the problem the question makes no sense and as such can't be answered.

Comment: ah, I see: it is about another question. You are right. I shall take care in the future. The code was added with an image and I meant to replace it with the text.